# Java: static factory method and thread safe

Tags: java

I want to get an object by a static factory method, such as

```
Person p = Person.fromName("Jack");

class Person {
    public static Person fromName(String name){
        return new Person(name);
    }
}
```

but fromName() method is not thread safe, (fromName() is just an example, this kind of method will occur error when it's running in my program) however, it's inefficient if synchronized this method because multiple threads should call this method concurrently. Is there any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: So you want an ObjectPool, that returns the same Person instance for the same given name? Otherwise, there should be no problem at all.

Comment: You want to make thread safe as well as allow multiple threads to access it simultaneously.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar Yes, that's what I want

Comment: Offtopic! actually stateless methods calls like the one shown in the example are thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems unsolvable when you say that

A) the method is not thread safe (thus needs to be used in a synchronized manner) and

B) it may not be synchronized due to efficiency reasons.

The only advice I can give you is to perform as **fine grained syncrhonization** as possible, i.e. only synchronize over thread-unsafe *parts* of the method.

If for instance statement `S1` needs to be performed atomically together with `S2` you could instead of doing

```
public synchronized static Person fromName(String name){
    ...
    S1;
    S2;
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

do

```
public static Person fromName(String name){
    ...
    synchronized (lock) {
        S1;
        S2;
    }
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that I can't use static factory method without synchronized, so I decide to use object method instead of class method.

Comment: Sure you can have synchronized static methods. Who told you that you can't use `synchronized` in static methods?

Answer (score 2):

If you've got code which is unsafe to execute in multiple threads concurrently, but you want to call it from multiple threads, it sounds like you really only have two options:

- *Make* it thread-safe
- Take the hit of serializing calls via synchronization

You haven't given any information which would suggest which of these is most appropriate in your situation. (Have you measured the performance hit of synchronization? Have you tried to make it thread-safe?)

Comment: Yes, I've tried to make it thread safe, but it's inefficient, so I decide to use object method instead of class method. thank you so much

Comment: @remy: That really doesn't explain anything about what you're doing...  it sounds like you might have some dubious beliefs about what thread safety involves...